# Cant get "x-appengine" headers in google app engine node js app

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform

I have a node-js express server in google app engine and I'm trying to read the request headers to get the user real ip and to find out if the request is from HTTP or HTTPS but i cannot get access to any x-* header in my request header object.

I added this code to the top of the server.js file:

```
app.set('trust proxy', true);
```

And I am trying to print the headers like this:

```
app.get('/**',function(req,res){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    console.log("req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']: " + req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']);
    console.log("req.headers['x-forwarded-for']: " + req.headers['x-forwarded-for']);
    console.log("req.headers['x-forwarded-host']: " + req.headers['x-forwarded-host']);
});
```

in my log files this is what I see:

```
{"host":"10.132.0.6","user-agent":"GoogleHC/1.0"}
 req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']: undefined
 req.headers['x-forwarded-for']: undefined
 req.headers['x-forwarded-host']: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

resolved.

Apparently I was looking on the wrong logs - I was actually looking on a health check request coming from the google load balance and the request was empty.